# Byobu doesn't start

Tags: byobu

When I run the byobu command I get this message. ***"/usr/bin/byobu-select-session: 24: exec: /usr/lib/byobu/include/select-session.py: not found"***. I am a beginner with bash so I don't know how to access certain files and here I have no clue of what to do.
If anyone has some idea I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

> This is because BYOBU_PYTHON is empty (python does not have snack module and byobu cannot set BYOBU_PYTHON).
>
> set python3 to BYOBU_PYTHON

```
sudo sed -i /usr/bin/byobu-select-session  -e 's;${BYOBU_PYTHON};python3;g'
```